# OpenLDAP sAMAccountName as custom attribute

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to add a custom attributes object class, because one of my applications only works with sAMAccountName.

I found out, that it needs the following schema to add it to LDAP.

```
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
NAME 'sAMAccountName'
SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'
SINGLE-VALUE )
```

I created a ldif file with this content and sAMAccountName appeared in Apache Directory Studio

```
dn: cn=custom-attributes,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: custom-attributes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
    NAME 'sAMAccountName'
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'
    SINGLE-VALUE )
```

But if I tried to add this attribute to my user I got an error #65, because it was not allowed by my object classes, so I removed it and tried to add a object class for custom attributes:

```
dn: cn=custom-attributes,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: custom-attributes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
    NAME 'sAMAccountName'
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'
    SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.100.1
    NAME 'customAttributes'
    SUP top
    AUXILIARY
    DESC 'Custom attributes class'
    MAY (sAMAccountName)
)
```

Now I am getting this error

> ldapadd: invalid format (line 6) entry: "cn=custom-attributes,cn=schema,cn=config"

I am adding the ldif file via terminal

```
ldapadd -H ldaps://ldap.mydomain.com/ -f samaccountname.ldif -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -w mypassword
```

Which line is meant by the error message? And whats wrong with the syntax?

I also heard about proxy the sAMAccountName to uid, but I did not find a example ldif file, so this solution seamed more achievable to me.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes a difference, but when I add custom attributes, I don't surround SYNTAX with single quotes. Perhaps this is a format error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is due to the last parenthesis. A new line on a LDIF file means a new item description. Try to put the last parenthesis at the end of the `MAY` line.